# How to localize a Wicket message in Java code?

Tags: java, localization, wicket

I follow this example:
https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/everything-about-wicket-internationalization.html
but I didnt found how to create localization message in java code.

My situation is:

```
try {

...

} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  // depends on language log message and show it in feedbackPanel
  error("");
}
```

I know I can add there some switch because I can get current locale but I dont think this is clear solution. I want to solve it througt Page.lanugage.properties where I have all localization messages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wicket provides a `getString()` on Component that does proper localisation.

In your example:

```
try {

 ...

} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    // depends on language log message and show it in feedbackPanel
    error(getString("some.property.id"));
}
```

Where `some.property.id` gets loaded via Wickets property loader from a property file.

Comment: I think you mean error(getString("some.property.id")); right?

Comment: this doesnt works in my app. My error:                         error("db.exception");
 and then I add to *.properties row: db.exception="CHyba aaaaaaaaa" but all I see is:  db.exception in my app